# Is nested routing possible in react-native?

Tags: react-native, nested-routes, react-router-native

I am using `react-router-native` for routing. Usually when ever new `route` is pushed to `history` the current screen will be unmounted and new screen is mounted. But As per [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting) nested routing is possible in web. They haven't mentioned anything about mobile.

I just want to know if nested routing is possible `react-native` as I want two routes to be active at a time.

Thank You.

Comment: Refer this https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/

Comment: @AkilaDevindaI had already gone through this which talks about web. But I would like to know the possibility in react-native. Any other alternative is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

in case of React Native use React navigation https://reactnavigation.org/ and its stack routing in case of mobile development where you mount a new view by navigate() and unmount by goback() to history
ref - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Comment: seems nested routing is possible with this package. But we have already implemented `react-router-native` in our package and not sure we can revert from it. So at least I would like to know if it is possible with `react-router-native`. Are you experienced with `react-router-native`?

Comment: Yes but react-router for web not in React Native :(
but react-router-native-stack might help you out